# Hive Vertex failed, vertexName=Map

Tags: hadoop, hive, tez

Hello All I have getting

> "Vertex failed, vertexName=Map"

error while inserting in to a hive table . .

> Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1,
> vertexId=vertex_1514985864009_4176244_3_00, diagnostics=[Task failed,
> taskId=task_1514985864009_4176244_3_00_000006,
> diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running
> task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error
> while processing row

Below is the other part of the error

> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run
>
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call

Comment: This isn't the actual error. You need to look at the Tez or YARN UI to find the real stacktrace

Comment: I have increase the container size , No I am not getting the Vertex failed error . But Now I have been getting the below error while inserting json data to a table . Below is the error 

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row

Comment: That's the same error, but not the actual exception that Hive is getting. Again, that exists in the YARN/Tez UI depending on if you're using MapReduce execution or not

Answer (score 0):

Trying changing the JOB to Map reducer from tez